# How to fill an existing array using Linq IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop, iteration

I have an Array of twenty item slot that is empty.

For example we just use simple int array

```
public int[] Integers = new int[20];
```

Then I have a database that hold lot of items

```
public int[] Database = new int[] {
    1, 2, 3, , ..., 1000
}
```

I would like to put some of items in database to my array

in Imperative I could just do:

```
// loop all my slots
for (int = 0; i < Integers.Length; i++) {

    // If database index of i is empty, then done this loop
    // correction: I'm putting null in case database type is not int
    if(Database[i] == null) {
        break;
    }
    // but when there's still something in database, fill it to current Integers[i]
    else {
        Integers[i] = Database[i] 
    }
}
```

But I wanted to make it in Linq, using Select and ForEach, however foreach doesn't have index i.

Note: I'm making a Inventory UI Item Slot in a game, so only twenty item inside the character could be seen in my UI at a time, it includes pagination also. I'm currently doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _slots.Count; i++)
    _slots[i].SetItem(i < InventoryItems.Count ? InventoryItems[i] : null);
```

with setItem as the side effects;

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for?

Comment: Can you talk us through why you don't want to use `var Integers = Database.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 20)).Take(20).ToArray();`? _This will get the first 20 entries from `Database` and pad with zeroes as required._

Comment: Can I do `Integers.Select( (x,i ) => {
x = Database[i];
return x;
})`;
Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion from my first comment?

Comment: I'm out for now, I'll try it later, but I think it might get error if I put it in twenty sized array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just omit `null`s:

```
Integers = Database.Where(i => i != null).ToArray();
```

Note that, if you want to check for `null` in `int` array, you need to make it `int?` (nullable type):

```
public int?[] Integers = new int[20];

public int?[] Database = new int[] {
  1, 2, 3, , ..., 1000
}
```

In fact, `Integer` can be `int[]`, as you select non-null values :)

**NOTE**: With code you have you are very prone to index out of range exception, as you apply same indexing to both arrays.

Comment: Oh that index out of range note is very helpful, thank you, was always wondering why I keep getting it.

Comment: @KevinTanudjaja If my answer helped you, you should accept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote :)

Comment: @KevinTanudjaja I can't, you have to explain what you want and what is not working. And also this should be another question instead of comment.

Comment: okay sorry, your code `Integers = Database.Where(i => i != null).ToArray();`
Is it going to be error? Is it fine putting the result to 20 sized array?

Comment: @KevinTanudjaja Don't initialize `Integers` as empty array, just initialize it with this code. If you initialize it the way you do it, you need to resize it.